# Template specialization with empty brackets and struct

Tags: templates, c++11

I am used to the template syntax of the form `struct hash<template class Key>` but what is the difference when using 
`template <> struct hash<Key>` ?

```
namespace std {

  template <>
  struct hash<Key>
  {
    std::size_t operator()(const Key& k) const
    {
      ....
    }
  };
}
```

Please note that I did search for the meaning of `template <>` and I understand (I hope) that it's a way, when using pattern matching to specify the non-matched case, but together with the usage of `struct<Key>` I do not understand the motivation of it.

Comment: That's the syntax for template specialization.

Comment: @melpomene In the context of structs/classes? Because if I have a template function, woudln't I specialize it using: template <class Key> void foo() {}

Comment: @user695652 That's not specialization, that's just a normal template declaration.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

There are different levels of template specialization:

1) Template declaration (no specialization)

```
template <class Key, class Value>
struct Foo {};
```

2) Partial specialization

```
template <class Key>
struct Foo<Key, int> {};
```

3) Full/explicit specialization

```
template <>
struct Foo<std::string, int> {};
```

Then, when instantiating the templates, the compiler will choose the most specialized definition available:

```
Foo<std::string, std::string> f1; // Should match #1
Foo<int,         int>         f2; // Should match #2
Foo<std::string, int>         f3; // Should match #3
```

#1 and #3 work for template functions as well.